# NullPointerException when MockMvc performed in unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, mockmvc

I'm trying to write a Java unit test but not sure where I'm going wrong. Likely a lack of understanding.

This is my test so far:

```
@Test
public void getURL() throws Exception {
    when(restTemplate.exchange(
            anyString(), eq(HttpMethod.GET), httpEntityCapture.capture(),
            ArgumentMatchers.<ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MyAP>>>any(),
            urlParamCapture.capture())).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(myAPs, HttpStatus.OK));
    when(restTemplate.exchange(
            anyString(), eq(HttpMethod.GET), httpEntity2Capture.capture(),
            eq(ReissueCert.class), urlParam2Capture.capture()))
            .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(reissueCert, HttpStatus.OK));
    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get(Endpoints.FWD_URL, "123")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
            .header("iv-user", email))
            .andExpect(status()
                    .isOk())
            .andReturn();
    assertEquals("Correct email sent", email, urlParamCapture.getValue());
    assertEquals("Correct dob", "07-09-1981", urlParam2Capture.getValue());
    assertEquals("Correct policy number", "123", urlParam3Capture.getValue());

}
```

When I run this I get a `NullPointerException`. The exception is from this line in my code:

```
ReissueURL reissue = docHelper.getURL(accountService.getAccountDetails(req.getHeader(Constants.IVUSER)).getId().toString(), accountService.getAccountDetails(req.getHeader(Constants.IVUSER)).getDob(), policy);
```

I think the problem is that no value ever exists for `req.getHeader(Constants.IVUSER)).getDob()` in my test. I'm not certain though and I'm not sure what to do next.

My debugger also shows this:

> Cannot find local variable 'urlParam2Capture'

Also, FYI a get on `Endpoints.FWD` should return something like this:

```
{
    "reissueURL": "https://hostname/product/logon.htm/product/reissue.htm?clientId=4609&dob=01-01-1980&policyNumber=123"
}
```

Here's the full stack trace:

> 14:13:15.005  INFO [service.name:myapi,,,] [main] INFO  o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor – Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
>
> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:645)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
> at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:72)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
> at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167)
> at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
> at brave.servlet.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:67)
> at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
> at ie.avis.myapi.config.TivoliAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(TivoliAuthenticationFilter.java:46)
> at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
> at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
> at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at ie.avis.myapi.config.TivoliAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(TivoliAuthenticationFilter.java:46)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:92)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
> at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
> at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
> at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.ExceptionLoggingFilter.doFilter(ExceptionLoggingFilter.java:50)
> at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
> at brave.servlet.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:84)
> at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.LazyTracingFilter.doFilter(TraceWebServletAutoConfiguration.java:138)
> at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
> at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:109)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
> at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:183)
> at ie.avis.myapi.controller.DocsControllerIT.getReissueCertURL(DocsControllerIT.java:283)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
> at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
> at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
> at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
> at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
> at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
> at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
> at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
> at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
> at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
> at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
> at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
> at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
> at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
> at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
> at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
> at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
> at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
> at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
> at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
> at ie.avis.myapi.service.account.AccountServiceReal.getAccountDetails(AccountServiceReal.java:72)
> at ie.avis.myapi.service.account.AccountServiceReal$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6c77a5a0.invoke()
> at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:687)
> at ie.avis.myapi.service.account.AccountServiceReal$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bc8047e0.getAccountDetails()
> at ie.avis.myapi.controller.DocsController.getReissueCertURL(DocsController.java:148)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
> ... 96 more

My `NullPointerException` comes from the `getAccountDetails` method:

```
public AccountDetails getAccountDetails(String username) {
    HttpHeaders headers = createHeaders();
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
    ResponseEntity<AccountDetails> response = restTemplate.exchange(accountAPIEndpoint + Constants.GET_ACCOUNT,
            HttpMethod.GET, request, AccountDetails.class, username);
    if (response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
        LOG.debug("Request successful. Returning AccountDetails.");
        return response.getBody();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I guess I need to mock an `AccountDetails` object for this. Is that correct and if so, how do I do that?

I'm attempting something like this:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    account1 = Account.builder().id(1L).username("foo").dob("07-09-1981").build();
}

...

public void getURL() throws Exception {
    when(restTemplate.exchange(
            anyString(), eq(HttpMethod.GET), httpEntityCapture.capture(),
            ArgumentMatchers.<ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MyAP>>>any(),
            urlParamCapture.capture())).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(myAPs, HttpStatus.OK));
    when(restTemplate.exchange(
            anyString(), eq(HttpMethod.GET), httpEntity2Capture.capture(),
            eq(ReissueCert.class), urlParam2Capture.capture()))
            .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(reissueCert, HttpStatus.OK));
    
    when(accountServiceReal.getAccountDetails("foo")).thenReturn(accountDetails);
    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get(Endpoints.FWD_URL, "123")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
            .header("iv-user", email))
            .andExpect(status()
                    .isOk())
            .andReturn();
    assertEquals("Correct email sent", email, urlParamCapture.getValue());
    assertEquals("Correct dob", "07-09-1981", urlParam2Capture.getValue());
    assertEquals("Correct policy number", "123", urlParam3Capture.getValue());

}
```

It's not working yet. Is this the correct approach though?

Comment: Please share exception stack trace. Also can you confirm if this is Parameterized test?

Comment: Added stack trace. It's currently setup to be a parameterized test although I'm not sure it needs to be.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at ie.avis.myapi.service.account.AccountServiceReal.getAccountDetails(AccountServiceReal.java:72)` , this is failing here, you might need to check why this call is failing in your application

Comment: I want to close it as duplicate of "what is NPE and how to fix it"....

Comment: I edited my question slightly based on this.